# Squirrel RestartApp does not seem to work in all cases

Tags: c#, squirrel.windows

I have a small adapter for [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows).

Which in one of the methods calls nothing other than [`RestartApp()`](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/51965fbd11b9f079e53290510b9042cdc4398f67/src/Squirrel/UpdateManager.cs#L176):

```
UpdateManager.RestartApp();
```

In some cases this works, however, in other it does not.
Is there any way of tracing/logging why this issue appears?

I could get source, add logging, but maybe there is some other way?
So far I have understood that when restart does not happen, it does not reach `SquirrelSetup.log` to make the entry.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Intexx no I have not unfortunately, please let me know if you get at the bottom of this

Comment: This isn't good news. I was having the same problem with ClickOnce; I'm just getting started with Squirrel. This is one of the problems I was hoping to solve. Did you open an issue at the GitHub repo? Paul is usually pretty quick to respond. I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: No, I have not done that, only went through discussions on issue tracker.

Comment: OK. Keep me posted and I'll do the same.

Comment: Could [this](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/1122) be your trouble? There doesn't seem to be a resolution, but at least you may be able to identify it.

Comment: @InteXX thanks for posting, this might as well be. Let me verify.